# How to hide DependencyPropery from Child Class?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a class treating it as base class for some functionality. Now I wanted to extend the working of that class. But here are some of the properties which I don't want to be shown by the users. so the question is how can hide some of Dependency properties.

I know about the `BrowsableAttribute` but I can't use it in my base class as this is being used by other classes. So I only want to hide some properties in the new extended class.

```
 public class BaseControl : Control
    {
        static BaseControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BaseControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BaseControl)));
        }



        public int BaseProperty
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(BasePropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BasePropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BaseProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BasePropertyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BaseProperty", typeof(int), typeof(BaseControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(100));


    }

    public class Child1Control : BaseControl
    {
      // Using BaseProperty for internal Uses. 
    }

    public class Child2Control : BaseControl
    { 
        //TODO: How To HIDE the BasePropery here so that
    }
```

Comment: Should the user be able to get to the property if they use the base class?

Comment: no that property need to be completely hidden.

Comment: Hard to say without an example, but why not setting them to `private`?

Comment: What is that DP? Post your current code.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: A `DependencyProperty` is always public, even if the .net accessor is not.

Comment: When you don't want all properties (functionality) of the base class then this is not a good case for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If the base class has properties that should not be accessible by child classes and should not be accessible by classing code, make the property private:

```
public MyBaseClass
{
    private string MyProperty { get; set; }


}
```

Or use private variables instead of properties:

```
public MyBaseClass
{
    private string _myProperty;


}
```

Comment: I should amend this to say that the ability to make properties private is available in any kind of class, not just classes used as bases for others :)

Comment: The question is about [DependencyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). Though dependency properties have CLR properties as wrappers, they must be public. If they are private, underlying Dependency Properties cannot be accessed by XAML, WPF property system.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to be overridden those property , simply register them as [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044.aspx)